# JList(linked with arraylist) adding element causes either high memory or dissapears

Tags: java, swing, memory, components, jlist

and sorry for my bad english. I have been having really hard time with a problem i am facing in an application im trying to do which uses java swing library for its GUI.

I will explain a simplier problem so you get it clearly (if i post the source code of my application will be harder to understand since i use different classes for each component etc...)

I am using a JList in order to show an arraylist of Persons. Take a look at the code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 111111; i++) {
            Person p = new Person(i);
            persons.add(p);
        }
        PersonList pl = new PersonList(persons);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(pl);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton addPerson = new JButton("add person");
        addPerson.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Person p = new Person(166);
                /*
                 * This will make the list dissapear.
                 */
                // persons.add(p);
                // pl.repaint();
                // pl.revalidate();
                /*
                 * This will cause high memory usage on each button click.
                 */
                jlist.Test.PersonList.PersonModel m = (jlist.Test.PersonList.PersonModel) pl.getModel();
                m.add(p);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(addPerson, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private class PersonList extends JList<Person> {
        private ArrayList<Person> listPersons;

        public PersonList(ArrayList<Person> persons) {
            this.listPersons = persons;
            setModel(new PersonModel());
            setCellRenderer(new PersonRenderer());
        }

        private class PersonRenderer extends JTextField implements ListCellRenderer<Person> {

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Person> list, Person value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                setText("height: " + value.getHeight());
                return this;
            }

        }

        private class PersonModel extends AbstractListModel<Person> {
            public void add(Person p) {
                listPersons.add(p);
                fireContentsChanged(this, listPersons.size(), listPersons.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public Person getElementAt(int arg0) {
                return listPersons.get(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return listPersons.size();
            }

        }
    }

    private class Person {
        private int height;

        public Person(int height) {
            this.setHeight(height);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

If i add the new Person into my main arraylist of data, then repaint & revalidate, list will dissapear **(in my main application, if i delete a Person first, then add one, it will work fine. If i add one more after, it will disappear, which means, i guess, something is wrong with its capacity/size of elements)**.

If i use fireContentsChanged method, JList will get the new Person and will be repainted fine. However, this causes used memory to be increased (by a lot) on each button click if i have a lot of items in my Jlist.

P.S: I have tried tons of things in order to make this work. I have written almost every StackOverflow posts that contain JList (no kidding). I have tried a lot of things with multithreading and swingworker but nothing changed.

Some of the things i used are:

Repainting my Scrollpane - does nothing.

Remove & Replacing my ScrollPane - Higher memory each time.

Replacing the whole Jlistmodel - higher memory each time.

Replacing the whole panel (in my main app) - higher memory each time.

Using setSize to the model - higher memory each time.

**EDIT:**
I use to watch the memory usage from Windows Task Manager, but in order to make sure, i use jconsole...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look to be over-complicating things a bit. For one, I wouldn't use a JTextField as my renderer but rather a use the DefaaultListCellRenderer and would add a border if one is desired. I also advise against extending JList but rather more simply using one. You could extend the model if need be, or more simply use a `DefaultListCellModel<Person>`.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int MAX_PERSONS = 111111;
    private DefaultListModel<Person> personModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(personModel);

    public Test2() {
        personJList.setPrototypeCellValue(new Person(11111111));
        personJList.setCellRenderer(new PersonRenderer());
        personJList.setVisibleRowCount(12);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(personJList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PERSONS; i++) {
            personModel.addElement(new Person(i));
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(new JButton(new AddPersonAction()), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class AddPersonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddPersonAction() {
            super("Add Person");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Person p = new Person(166);
            personModel.addElement(p);
        }
    }

    private class PersonRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (value != null) {
                value = ((Person) value).getHeight();
            } else {
                value = "";
            }
            JComponent renderer = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
                    index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            // if you want a border around your renderer:
            renderer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            return renderer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Test2 mainPanel = new Test2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
public class Person {
    private int height;

    public Person(int height) {
        this.setHeight(height);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```